# Remove Fotorama and output only images (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, fotorama-slider

Trying to figure out how to remove Fotorama from product detail page and just output all the images on page. I want to make another style for this part.
Since longtime searching for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the file on .../vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html and remove fotorama classes

See too this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5302